# How to center webpage content with many div structures

Tags: html, css, center, footer

I was working on a page that I want to make the page in the center of the browser. It's working as expected when it's zooming in.  But when it zoomed out, the page gets shifted to the right.   Can someone tell me what I did wrong?  Thanks.

[image]

If I zoom-out this becomes:
[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<body onload="init()";>

<!-- container panel-->
<div id="container">  

    <!-- header panel-->
    <div class="header">sssss</div>

    <div id="main">
    <!-- left panel-->

        <div class="leftpanel">sssss</div>

        <div class="rightpanel">
            <div class="toppanel">sssss</div>
            <div class="content">sssss</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- footer-->
    <div class="footer">sssss</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also this is the css part:

```
#bg1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #8888ff;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 280px 60px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 15px 5px #444444;
}
#main
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 60px 28px 0px 28px;
    width: 1124px;
}
body 
{ 
    float: center;
    text-align: center; 
    width: 1500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: 7777ff;
} 
.leftpanel
{
    width: 18%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10;
    padding-top: 20;
    margin-bottom: 40;
    background: orange;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
}
.rightpanel
{
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 0 0 160px;
}
.toppanel
{
    margin-left: 70px;
    background-color: #fbbbb9;
    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;   
}
.content
{
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}
.box {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer
{
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` should not have a `width` of 1500px, should be 100%;
`#container` should be `max-width:1000px;`  `width:100%;`
Also, anchor `#container` to `body`

Please make these changes:

```
#bg1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #8888ff;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 280px 60px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
body #container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    max-width:1000px;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 15px 5px #444444;
}
#main
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 60px 28px 0px 28px;
    width: 1124px;
}
body 
{ 
    float: center;
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: 7777ff;
} 
.leftpanel
{
    width: 18%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10;
    padding-top: 20;
    margin-bottom: 40;
    background: orange;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
}
.rightpanel
{
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 0 0 160px;
}
.toppanel
{
    margin-left: 70px;
    background-color: #fbbbb9;
    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;   
}
.content
{
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}
.box {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer
{
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

You can see this in action on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MX9kC/

Comment: Also when I zoom-out the page is still in the center, but you can see there's extra space in the right of the page.  Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I think it MIGHT be that `#main` width is larger than container, should make #main width 100% as well.  As a pro tip, should never use width use max-width and % so the web site you're making will be responsive to different devices.

Comment: You can also do `overflow:hidden` on #main, but I think it should be smaller width because #main's x,y position is at the top left of #container.  What browser are you using?  You should use chrome inspector or firefox firebug, they REALLY help you with css a LOT. saved my life millions of time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width on the `<body>` tag and that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<body onload="init()";>

<!-- container panel-->

<center>
<div id="container">  

    <!-- header panel-->
    <div class="header">sssss</div>

    <div id="main">
    <!-- left panel-->

        <div class="leftpanel">sssss</div>

        <div class="rightpanel">
            <div class="toppanel">sssss</div>
            <div class="content">sssss</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- footer-->
    <div class="footer">sssss</div>

</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

it will work

Comment: Don't use <center> . It's ancient and deprecated. This also won't solve the issue.